# Android: Why shouldn't I use activities inside tabs?

Tags: android, tabs, android-activity

I've read at a few places that I should not be using Activities as contents of my tabs. I would like to know why this is not a recommended approach... Any suggestions?

Comment: This might be why: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1306689/launching-activities-within-a-tab-in-android

Comment: Oh... Thanks... that does sound like a complex requirement. If that isn't the case, am I ok with it? I mean, I would still use activities in the tabs to launch other activities but I don't mind if the activities are launched "outside" the tabs... Any thoughts?

Comment: Here is a link that may help: **Tabs with Intents**<br>
[http://www.androidguys.com/2008/12/05/tabs-with-intents/](http://www.androidguys.com/2008/12/05/tabs-with-intents/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd flip it around: why would you want to use activities as tabs? All you do is add overhead and complexity. Just use Views for the tabs.

If you have something that just *has* to be both a tab and a separate standalone activity, reuse the View.

Comment: Actually I was more tempted by your tutorial (posted by Robert in the previous post)... Correct me if I'm wrong, but by using separate intents for the tabs, I will be doing an on-demand loading. So for instance, if there are three listviews, I will be loading just one... Or is it the same if I use Views as well?

I am trying to understand the fundamental difference between using either approach...

Comment: So all I'm seeing is starting one huge activity versus starting an activity on demand... I could be wrong but I'd really appreciate if you can correct me...

Comment: Thanks a ton! That's exactly the way I was looking for... Just wish Java had partial classes... My main class is growing super huge now...