# Added new Activities to a Tabbed Activity

Tags: android

I have added 4 activities to a tabhost widget. These work fine. The problem is that i have started a new activity from my of my activity that is present in the TabbedHost. This activity is started on a new screen i.e The tabs are no longer visible. How can i start a new activity and it remains within the tabbed host. I hope u understand what i mean?

Kind Regards,
Mateen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hah!! Thats the problem with Tabhost widget dude! They don't allow you to start another activity in the tabhost itself.

The way i worked around is save the state by assigning them to some variables and then change the whole `contentView` itself by calling the `context.setContentView(R.layout.newLayout)`...

Then after loading the contentView you'll have to override the

```
@Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    //check if this has been called by your second view, if yes then
    //set the previous ContentView and assign the values accordingly
    //else super.onKeyDown(keyCode,event)
    }
```

Worked like a charm for me... you can also do the same thing by having a back button in the second view of yours... Its your call...

you can further refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1984791)...

Comment: @st0le... oh Thanx dude... u didnt give me an upvote so i thought mayb u didnt like the idea... :)