# Android keep tabview when click on a list view item

Tags: android, listview, android-activity, window, tabview

I currently have a `tabview` with three tabs. In one tab i have a `listview`. I currently have each item on the list to display a new window/activity/intent when i click on it. Is it possible to do this and still have the `tabview` displaying at the same time? Thanks

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1984791/android-tabs-starting-a-new-activity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yea It is possible.
You need an `ActivityGroup` class, Which helps navigation in `TabActivity`, and the tabs always remain visible and accessible.

[**Here**](http://ericharlow.blogspot.com/2010/09/experience-multiple-android-activities.html) is a usefull link to a tutorial.

But using `ActivityGroup` creates a little, very little complexity about the `Context` and opening `Dialog`s (adding new Windows) in child `Activity`(ies), but the more you understand the miner will be the complexity.

Comment: how can we solve same problem if i replace activitygroup with listfragments and activity with fragementactivity.