# Is it better to create new Activities or just create a different Layout and replace the existing layout?

Tags: android

Since I am new to Android, I am now thinking on what is the correct way of doing things.

As it stands, the application I'm writing has 4 different screens:

- Screen 1 - list of nodes (main screen)
- Screen 2 - options menu, tableLayout with buttons
- Screen 3 - navigation
- Screen 4 - text details on version etc

These screens can be navigated to/from using a "header" View that is placed on top. The header then has 4 different buttons:

```
+--------------------+
| menu with buttons  |
+--------------------+
|                    |
|                    |
|                    |
|  C O N T E N T     |
|                    |
|                    |
|                    |
+--------------------+
```

**main.xml** is really just a LinearLayout that INCLUDES the header.xml and then the content, in that case the list of nodes in a ListView

**options.xml** is the same thing almost, it includes the headerxml and then a bunch of buttons...

...and so on with the two other screens.

So, when I press one of the buttons in the header/menu on top the content should be switched to that screen. **My question is:**

- Should I create one Activity for each screen? I read on Google that:
  *An activity presents a visual user interface for one focused endeavor the user can undertake.* So that can be interpreted that I should use one Activity for each of these screens.
- Should I **not** create more Activities than the startup, and then just run the *setContentView(R.layout.whatever)* when I want to change the "content" above?

Comment: As a follow-up question to that:                   
the header, as defined in header.xml, has 4 buttons. Where do I attach the click listeners for those? I do not have a specific Activity for the header.xml. Should I have that? Or should I attach listeners in my Main.java Activity?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should probably use a separate `Activity` for each screen; otherwise you need to end up keeping track of which individual `View` is currently being displayed, plus the state of all those not currently being displayed when the user switches to another window, or a call comes in etc.

It's easier to keep track of this state if you just use a separate `Activity` for each piece of functionality.

If you do decide to keep everything in a single `Activity` however, you could look at the [`TabActivity`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/TabActivity.html) class. However, there are also caveats there that prevent you from having an `Activity` as the tab content.

- [Android: Why shouldn't I use activities inside tabs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1568739/android-why-shouldnt-i-use-activities-inside-tabs)

---

Regarding your follow-up, you unfortunately cannot attach an `Intent` directly to a `Button` like you can with a `MenuItem` via the XML, however you could just extend `Activity` to make your own common base class with some code that hooks up the listeners.

Something like:

```
public class BaseActivity extends Activity {
    protected View.OnClickListener mButtonListener;

    protected void setupHeaderButtons() {
        findViewById(R.id.header_btn_1).setOnClickListener(mButtonListener);
        // ...
        findViewById(R.id.header_btn_n).setOnClickListener(mButtonListener);
    }
}

public class FirstActivity extends BaseActivity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle b) {
        super.onCreate(b);
        setContentView(R.layout.first_activity);

        // This needs to be done *after* the View has been inflated
        setupHeaderButtons();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thx, do you have any comments on my follow-up question above? Should the header have its on Activity, and can I <include> it as I can with a View?

Comment: I updated my answer. Activities can't include other activies. But an Activity's layout can include other layouts. You would just include header.xml in each Activity's layout XML using the `<include>` tag.

Comment: Thx, for the follow-up answer. I will take a look at it =)

Comment: I didnt get it to work, and I think I need more help so I posted a new question here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2013865/header-views-and-buttons-how-do-i-attach-listeners-to-buttons-in-a-header-th), and referred back to this thread. Thx again =)

Answer (score 2):

I am also quite new to Android but my advice would be to create 4 different Activities. The reason for that is that it seems like a "cleaner" implementation to me. Sure, there is more code to be written but I'd rather have more small classes than one big class with lots of code in it.

Comment: Thx for the answer =) If you have something nice to say about my follow-up question above, Id appreciate it =)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this has been mentioned in any of the sub questions, but if you change activities pre-2.0 you cannot animate between them.

So if you have a loading screen and would like it to fade to a menu you have to use two views and switch between the two.