# FragmentActivity with a Fragment Containing a MapView

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-mapview, android-maps, android-compatibility

I know there are a few questions like this but what I'm looking for is slightly different the way I see it.

**THE PROBLEM**

I have one `Activity` and I am only ever going to have one `Activity`.

I do however have multiple `Fragments`; one of which contains a `MapView`.

I have successfully got this working in `API level 3.0` and greater. However, the problems start when I want to go lower than this using the compatibility library as I then need to make my `Activity` extend `FragmentActivity` to get `Fragments` to work and then I obviously lose the ability to also extend `MapActivity`

**THE QUESTION**

How can I use the `Compatibility Support Library` to enable the use of `Fragments` and a `MapView` within the same `Activity`?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**P.S** I personally think it's ridiculous they didn't include support for this within the `Compatibility Support Library`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've done exactly this! Using this:

https://github.com/petedoyle/android-support-v4-googlemaps

It took some time, but with this, I've been able to have Fragments and a MapView inside the same Activity down to 2.3 (probably lower, as well). You basically get the jar from that github site, which is called android-support-v4-r7-googlemaps.jar, and use that instead of the default support library. With that, your main activity still extends FragmentActivity (which is extending MapActivity in the background).

There should be a readme at that same link for further direction.

Comment: And yes, it is ridiculous. :P Upon searching, that's mostly what I found: people saying the same thing haha.