# getCurrentActivity() and ActivityGroup

Tags: android

I am using an ActivityGroup and when I finish a top-level Activity (e.g. with destroyActivity method) and display one from history, the getCurrentActivity method returns the last Activity - the finished one. I need to access currently displayed activity, which is actually shown.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to do or why. Could you provide a bit more detail on what your trying to do, why it isn't working and any errors you get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it looks like getCurrentActivity() in single task mode returns only the latest started activity, without taking care of history. A workaround is to keep Activities' Ids, so getActivity(String id) can be used.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1306689/launching-activities-within-a-tab-in-android/6371778#6371778