# How to show Android tab bar when opening a new window

Tags: android, tabbar

I wrote a simple Android program with 2 tabs. Tab 1 has a button which will open a new window. But I realized that when opening this new window, the Android tab bar will be hidden.

I'd like to always show the Android tab bar. Can anyone tell me how to do that?

Comment: You'll need to create a content container and load your content there, so your tabs aren't covered up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should see this post, he explained the same thing in very detail
[Launching activities within a tab in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1306689/launching-activities-within-a-tab-in-android)