# TabWidget problem with new activities

Tags: android

I use Tab Widget like in documentation example [TabWidget](http://developer.android.com/guide/tutorials/views/hello-tabwidget.html)

I have two tabs, and in every tab when I press some button I need to load another different activity. My question is how to achive that I have that two tab on another activities like headers ?
I could create that tabs in new activities but it wouldn't remember choosen activity for another tab. How to solve this ?

Comment: To clarify, you are trying to reload a new Activity into your current tab?

Comment: Yes, new activity in my tab, but not to change another in second tab . And viceversa.

Comment: seems like this [another thread on stackoverflow][1] can help


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1306689/launching-activities-within-a-tab-in-android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible out of the box. The normal TabHost doesn't provide any facility to change the content of a tab after it is created. If you can use views as your tab content, you can, however, flip between the views within a tab so that to get the effect you are after.

If you absolutely must use a new Activity, then you will have to implement your own TabHost which allows swapping tab content after it is created.

Comment: @nEx.Software how can i flip from one view to another to achieve that effect?