# (android) Change tab instead of startActivity

Tags: android, tabs, tabview

Well as i say i have a tabView on my program and i want to pass some data through the activities. When i try startActivity the tabs disappear. So i want instead of trying startActivity. I Want to change the tab.

I have 3 activities one for each tab and one separate to hold the tabview.

```
public class Start extends TabActivity {
TabHost tabHost;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.start);

Resources res = getResources(); // Resource object to get Drawables
tabHost = getTabHost();  // The activity TabHost
TabHost.TabSpec spec;  // Reusable TabSpec for each tab
Intent intent;  // Reusable Intent for each tab

intent = new Intent().setClass(this, Home.class);
spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Home").setIndicator("Home",
                  res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_main))
              .setContent(intent);
tabHost.addTab(spec);

// Do the same for the other tabs
intent = new Intent().setClass(this, History.class);
spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("History").setIndicator("History",
                  res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_history))
              .setContent(intent);
tabHost.addTab(spec);

intent = new Intent().setClass(this, Settings.class);
spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Settings").setIndicator("Settings",
                  res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_settings))
              .setContent(intent);
tabHost.addTab(spec);

tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
```

thats how i add the tabs and i dont know how to change the tab from an other activity. I tried this:

```
  Start tab;
  tab.tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
```

but i got error.... :/

Comment: I don't really get what you want to do.Can you please explain a little more?

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1306689/launching-activities-within-a-tab-in-android

Comment: I have total 4 activities. 1 holds the TabView (Start.java) and another 3 activities one for each tab. i want to pass some data between the activities but when i try startActivity i got the activity on screen but all the tabs are disappear. So instead of startactivity i want to just change the tab so the tas wont disappear and i dont know how to change the tab programmaticaly

Answer (score 0):

You should check out the ActivityGroup class.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityGroup.html

And here it is shown in action:

http://united-coders.com/nico-heid/use-android-activitygroup-within-tabhost-to-show-different-activity

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to call `startActivity` to switch between tabs, the TabHost takes care of that for you.
As for passing data between the tabs, have you considered storing the data in the tabActivity? You can get a reference to it from your tabs (the childrens) by using `getParent()` and casting it to your class, in your case `(Start)`
Like this:

```
Start parentActivity;
parentActivity = (Start) getParent();
```

Now you can access data and methods you create in the tabActivity.