# Tabbar does not show when i am clicking inside the tab bar class in android

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Launching activities within a tab in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1306689/launching-activities-within-a-tab-in-android)

I have tab bar it contains 4 tabs,each one call diff activity.In that class i have list view its item click call another activity.At that time the tab bar was not shown...I want app as, i call any activity in app,it always will show the tab bar.please help me.

Comment: [Duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1306689/1050058)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use FragmentActivity, FragmentListView to get that. You will be replacing current fragment with next screen in the flow (which is also a fragment). you will have to manage your own backstack, so that something meaningful happens when user presses back button.

refer [Fragment for All](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2011/03/fragments-for-all.html), [Fragment](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html), [Fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html), [Fragment Tutorial](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-compatibility-working-with-fragments/)

Comment: I Didn't understand,Any example source code you have..