# Android Tab Layout Design - Best Approach

Tags: android, android-layout, tabs

I'm developing an application and I want to place two activities in a tabbed layout. I need the ability for the first activity to send an intent and programmatically switch to the second tabbed activity. This seems possible and is outlined in other posts:

[Launching activities within a tab in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1306689/launching-activities-within-a-tab-in-android)

However, this approach doesn't seem advisable and it makes use of ActivityGroup, which is now deprecated. Can anyone recommend a stable solution that would meet my design needs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to take a look at `ViewPager` from the support library, coupled with  https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator/blob/master/library/src/com/viewpagerindicator/TabPageIndicator.java

It will produce a tab-like interface that you can swipe through. You can explicitly change which tab is being shown by calling `viewPager.setCurrentItem(int)`.