# Android: tabhost with more intent than tabs

Tags: android, android-intent, tabs

here's my questions:
i have a normal tabactivity, with my three tabs defined like this one:

```
    TabSpec listatabs= tabHost.newTabSpec("App");
    listatabs.setIndicator("Lista", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.mia_lista));
    Intent listaIntent = new Intent(this, MIALISTA.class);
    listaIntent .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    listatabs.setContent(listaIntent );
    // Aggiungo i tabs
    tabHost.addTab(listatabs);
```

the problem is: if the user go in this tab (which have a list of items), and click on a item, i must call a new intent to display the content (and of course a new .class)... but i must remain in the intrested tab.
how can i implement this idea?

Comment: Are these items, that you talk about, tabs? Or are they other activities that you want to see under the current tab?

Comment: other activity... i think it's an idea like this, but i'm not sure because it's a new things for me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1306689/launching-activities-within-a-tab-in-android

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a custom ActivityGroup:

Make a class TabGroupActivity:

```
public class TabGroupActivity extends ActivityGroup {

private ArrayList<String> mIdList;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (mIdList == null) mIdList = new ArrayList<String>();
}

/**
* This is called when a child activity of this one calls its finish method.
* This implementation calls {@link LocalActivityManager#destroyActivity} on the child activity
* and starts the previous activity.
* If the last child activity just called finish(),this activity (the parent),
* calls finish to finish the entire group.
*/
@Override
public void finishFromChild(Activity child) {
    LocalActivityManager manager = getLocalActivityManager();
    int index = mIdList.size()-1;

    if (index < 1) {
        finish();
        return;
    }

    manager.destroyActivity(mIdList.get(index), true);
    mIdList.remove(index);
    index--;
    String lastId = mIdList.get(index);
    Intent lastIntent = manager.getActivity(lastId).getIntent();
    Window newWindow = manager.startActivity(lastId, lastIntent);
    setContentView(newWindow.getDecorView());
}

/**
* Starts an Activity as a child Activity to this.
* @param Id Unique identifier of the activity to be started.
* @param intent The Intent describing the activity to be started.
* @throws android.content.ActivityNotFoundException.
*/
public void startChildActivity(String Id, Intent intent) {
    Window window = getLocalActivityManager().startActivity(Id,intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP));
    if (window != null) {
        mIdList.add(Id);
        setContentView(window.getDecorView());
    }
}

/**
* The primary purpose is to prevent systems before android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.ECLAIR
* from calling their default KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK during onKeyDown.
*/
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
//preventing default implementation previous to android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.ECLAIR
return true;
}
return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}

/**
* Overrides the default implementation for KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK
* so that all systems call onBackPressed().
*/
@Override
public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        onBackPressed();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyUp(keyCode, event);
}

/**
* If a Child Activity handles KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK.
* Simply override and add this method.
*/
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    int length = mIdList.size();
    if ( length > 1) {
        Activity current = getLocalActivityManager().getActivity(mIdList.get(length-1));
        current.finish();
    }
}
```

in your custom Activity, for example 'HomeTabGroupActivity':

```
public class HomeTabGroupActivity extends TabGroupActivity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    startChildActivity("HomeMainActivity", new Intent(this, HomeMainActivity.class));

}
}
```

in Activity A, use this to go to activityB:

```
Intent i = new Intent(getParent(),ActivityB.class);
        TabGroupActivity parentActivity = (TabGroupActivity)getParent();
        parentActivity.startChildActivity("ActivityB", i);
```

and let the tab take you to 'HomeTabGroupActivity'

Let me know if you want to use startActivityForResult within the tabgroup, ill post a little fix for that.

Comment: i'm trying to implement this, i'll let you know