# Tab view activity roload

Tags: android, android-tabhost, android-tablelayout, android-tabs

How can I close a `tab` when I am leaving that tab.

or

How can I start an `activity` when I am clicking a `tab` each time.

Comment: When you set intent for your Tab, also Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP for your intent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set tab change listener

```
getTabHost().setOnTabChangedListener(new OnTabChangeListener() {

@Override
public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {

int i = getTabHost().getCurrentTab();
 Log.i(" ANN CLICK TAB NUMBER",  + i);

    if (i == 0) {
            Log.i("Inside onClick tab 0", "onClick tab");

    }
    else if (i ==1) {
            Log.i("Inside onClick tab 1", "onClick tab");
    }

  }
});
```

Depend on your activity stack if your current exactly on top of the parent activity you can just finish current actvity and it will go to previous activity. If you want to clear all activity stack and start over new activity try

```
Intent intent1 = new Intent(context, activity.class);
             intent1.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
             intent1.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);  
            startActivity(intent1);
```

Comment: I saw that ans But please tell me how can I restart or finish that that activity using that TAB NUMBER

Comment: How can I open that intent1 inside a tabview

Comment: That activity is opeing but not inside tabview please tell me how to

Comment: i think if you do searching you got might have got your answer anyways this may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1306689/launching-activities-within-a-tab-in-android